# How to pass a range of dates through the for loop in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, unix

I am new to Bash so please help me articulate this question better if need be.

Let's say I have a `.sh` script. This script performs some calculation on some data for each day of the previous week from Sunday through Saturday (the week starts on Sunday). For e.g. Today, I am running this script for data starting 23rd Feb 2020 through 29th Feb 2020. When running the script on my terminal, I provide 3 parameters- year, month and day

```
./scriptname.sh ${yyyy} ${mm} ${dd}
```

Now, most of the time, I am fine with something like this

```
yyyy=2020; mm=02; for dd in seq 23 -w 29; do ./scriptname.sh ${yyyy} ${mm} ${dd}; done
```

But almost every month there is a week that spills over to the next month (e.g the week running from 29th March through 4th April). At first I thought I could automate this a little bit using variables

```
start_day=$(date -d "last-sunday -7 days" +%d);
end_day=$(date -d "last-saturday" +%d);
start_month=$(date -d "last-sunday -7 days" +%m);
end_month=$(date -d "last-saturday" +%m);
```

So the above script changes to something like this (had to exclude the backtick around seq for formatting sake)

```
yyyy=2020; for mm in  ${start_month} ${end_month}; do for dd in  seq -w ${start_day} ${end_day}; do ./scriptname.sh ${yyyy} ${mm} ${dd}; done; done
```

But it creates all the permutations of `dd` and `mm`. How do I make sure I only pass these 7 relevant values for `${yyyy} ${mm} ${dd}`?

```
2020 03 29
2020 03 30
2020 03 31
2020 04 01
2020 04 02
2020 04 03
2020 04 04
```

Comment: You seem to aware of `seq`. Then `for i in $(seq 1 5)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it yourself. Dates are tricky, months have variable number of days, etc. Your script also needs additional handling of years. Let `date` handle calculations with dates.

```
for i in {1..7}; do ./scriptname.sh $(date --date="-$i days" "+%Y %m %d"); done
```

> .g the week running from 29th March through 4th April

The way I would do it is to take 29th Match as number of seconds since epoch. Then add half a day so that leap seconds if any are not an isssue. Then just increment it by number of seconds in a day and use `date` to convert it back to a date.

```
then=$(date --date='2020/03/29 12:00:00' +%s);
for i in {0..6}; do 
     ./scriptname.sh $(date --date="@$((then + $i * 60 * 60 * 24))" "+%Y %m %d");
done
```

Alternatively, you can do it without `then` variable, but you have to remember that the number `+0` immediately coming after date is interpreted as timezone.

```
for i in {0..6}; do ./scriptname.sh $(date --date="2020/03/29 12:00:00 +0 +$i days" '+%Y %m %d'); done
```

Because I like streaming-like parsing in bash, I would parse the output with `xargs`:

```
seq 6 | xargs -I{} date -d '2020/03/29 12:00:00Z +{} days' '+%Y %m %d' | xargs -n3 ./scriptname.sh
```

Comment: I only need to supply values of year month and day so I like the first approach better. As is, it's passing a date range from 2020 02 24 to 2020 03 01. What I need is 2020 02 23 to 2020 02 29 (the range of the previous week) How do I modify it?

Comment: The 3rd code snippet is not that hard to follow. `{0..6}` is the range whereas `2020/03/29` is current date and `+$i days` tells will be traveling forward (as opposed to `-$i days`).. You want `for i in {0..6}; do echo $(date --date="2020/02/29 12:00:00+0 -$i days" '+%Y %m %d'); done`? Or `for i in {0..6}; do echo $(date --date="2020/02/23 12:00:00+0 +$i days" '+%Y %m %d'); done`?

Comment: Okay that does give me the expected output I want but looks like I have to manually specify today's date. Correct?

Comment: ? I do not fully understand. You have specify one date, at least. The date you start from. Or the date you end on. The interval you specified always to be 7 days. You want `for i in {1..7}; do echo $(date --date="last-sunday -$i days" "+%Y %m %d"); done`? Really, the date specifying string for GNU `date` is very... flexible.

Comment: The date always start on the Sunday of the previous week and ends on the following Saturday. E.g if i am running this script today, I would be running it for 23rd Feb through 29th Feb. That's why I was wondering if the first approach could be modified to work without having to specify an explicit date

Comment: Yes it can be modified. See my previous comment. Here (where I live) weeks start with monday: `for i in {0..6}; do echo $(date --date="last-monday +$i days" "+%Y %m %d %A"); done` ; )

Answer (score 1):

Another example, calculating days using seconds:

```
for s in $(seq $(date -d "last-sunday -7 days" +%s) 86400 $(date -d "last-sunday" +%s)); do date --date=@$s "+%Y %m %d"; done
```

Comment: Had to change the 2nd "last-sunday" to "last-saturday" but I like this approach too.